# How to find keywords of the users input in the command line?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, find, findstr

What I'm looking for is a batch file line of code that will scan what the user inputs to find key words and direct them in the right place. That way when a trainee has a question he/she could just ask the batch file and it will direct them to the proper menu. Is this possible? if so, How would one go about doing this?

```
:menu
set /p c=Please type you question: 
findstr /m "How to ringout a product on our system?" "%c%"
if %c%=="ringout" (
    goto :Ringingout
    ) Else (
        goto :Sorry
        )

:Ringingout
cls 
echo In order to right something out maksure you do the following:
echo - Log in
echo - click on scan in the bottom left had corner on the tender page
echo - scan items
echo - click continue
Pause
goto :Menu

:Sorry
cls
echo Sorry I don't recognize your question, please re-word it.
pause
goto :Menu
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "keywords=word anotherword someword"
FOR %%k IN (%keywords%) DO set "#%%k="

SET /p query="Please enter your query ? "
FOR %%k IN (%keywords%) DO CALL :analyse %%k

SET #

GOTO :EOF

:analyse
CALL SET "found=%%query:%1=%%"
IF "%found%"=="%query%" GOTO :EOF 
SET #%1=FOUND!
GOTO :eof
```

Here's a general way to do it.

If one of the keywords is entered, the variable `#keyword` will be set to `FOUND!` so you can use `if defined #keyword` to process from there.

It's not protected against destructive user-inputs - that's not what this question is about...

Comment: As I said, `if defined #word goto whateverforword`

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off collecting all the questions in a document (like .html) and letting the user search that document for what they need.  But if this is just an exercise, you can re-write your logic like so to make your program work:

```
:menu
set "c="
set /p "c=Please type your question: "

echo %c% | findstr /i /b "ringout" >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto Sorry else goto Ringingout

:Ringingout
```

and so on.